# Help with MySQL query combining 2 tables with LIKE AND OR statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get results for articles that have a title or subcategory name similar to the request.

```
Table 1
Subcategory_ID Subcategory_Name

Table 2
Article_ID   Title  Subcategory_ID
```

Now I need to fetch articles from table 2 where title or subcategory_names match what we're looking for.

Here is what I have, but I can't come up with the rest

```
 SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1,table2 WHERE table2.title = '%keyword%'
```

and the rest I mess up...

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1, table2 
  WHERE table1.Subcategory_ID=table2.Subcategory_ID 
  AND (table2.title LIKE '%keyword%' OR table1.Subcategory_Name LIKE '%keyword%')
```

With MySQL INNER JOIN it is implicit if you use "table1.Subcategory_ID=table2.Subcategory_ID" in the WHERE clause.

Comment: DoXicK answer includes all table1 entries which has no table2 entry (LEFT JOIN), when mine not (INNER JOIN)...

Comment: indeed, i've been writing left joins all day so i guess i'm kind of in the mood for it ;-) Thanks for the heads up, fixed it!

Comment: Well, i just commented in case the OP needs a LEFT JOIN. The original post doesnt specify if a table2 entry is needed for each table1 entry or not. Maybe it makes sense for him to have table2 entries (articles) without any table1 related entry (subcategories), which will make it a RIGHT JOIN... Depends on him! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT t2.Title, t1.Subcategory_Name
FROM Table2 t2 JOIN Table1 t1
ON t2.Subcategory_ID = t1.Subcategory_ID
WHERE t2.title LIKE '%keyword%' OR t1.Subcategory_Name LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 USING (Subcategory_id) 
  WHERE table2.title LIKE '%keyword%'
```

You can replace `USING (Subcategory_id)` with `ON (table1.subcategory_id = table2.subcategory_id)`.

For more explanation see *[MySQL Tutorial - Join](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php)*.

Answer (score 0):

May be by

```
select t1.*,t2.* 
  from `table2` t2 join `table1` t1 
  on t1.Subcategory_ID = t2.Subcategory_ID 
  where t2.title LIKE '%keyword%' or t1.Subcategory_Name LIKE '%keyword%'
```